# Using "rule of zero" when I have pointers for polymorphism

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, copy-constructor

For the "rule of zero", I understand that I want to separate data management out into simple classes implementing rule of 3, rule of 5, whatever, so that the the more complicated classes can use constructors, assignment operators, etc, as automatically provided.

How does this work when a class member has to be a pointer because of polymorphism?

E.g., suppose I have a class

```
class MyClass{
private:
 s_array<int> mynumbers;
 s_array<double> mydoubles;

 Base * object;
 ...
 };
```

Here, `Base` is a base class with multiple derived classes, and `object` may be point to one of the derived classes.  So `object` is a pointer in order to get polymorphism.

If it wasn't for the presence of this `Base` pointer, I could use the rule-of-zero for `MyClass` assuming `s_array<>` is properly implemented.  Is there a way to set things up so that `MyClass` can use the rule of zero, even though object is a pointer?  The behavior that I want on copy is that a new instance of `MyClass` gets a pointer to a new copy of `object`.

Comment: Use a smart pointer class that has the behavior you want, instead of an unmanaged raw pointer.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Base> object;` is the straightforward way.

Comment: If your class manages resources, then it's not possible to apply Rule of Zero. But as mentioned above, you can move that burden to smart pointers and your class won't need to manage anything.

Comment: If you insist that `MyClass` contains a pointer which points at a managed resource, then `MyClass` cannot comply with the the rule of zero.      The management of the object needs to be relegated to another class, which follows the rule of 3 or 5 as needed (e.g. copy constructor that handles needed cloning of the pointed-to object).   Then your `MyClass` can either inherit from that manager class, or have one (or more) instance of that manager class as a member  INSTEAD OF having `object` as a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the rule of 0 with pointers, you need to use a shared pointer:

```
shared_ptr<Base> object;
```

However this doesn't fully fulfil your requirement.  Because `shared_ptr` will provide for the rule of 5, but the copied pointers will always point to the same original object.

To get the behavior that you want, you'd need to create your own smart pointer that provides for the rule of 3 or 5.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple `MyClass` objects can point to the same `Base` object, then simply use `std::shared_ptr<Base>` instead of `Base*` for your `object` member, as other responders mentioned.

But, if each `MyClass` object needs to point to its own `Base` object, then you have no choice but to implement the Rule of 3/5 in `MyClass` so that it can create its own `Base` object and/or clone a `Base` object from another `MyClass` object.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, what I using to solve this is the following (basically as suggested as above):

```
template <class myClass>
class clone_ptr
{
public:
  clone_ptr(){location=nullptr;}
  clone_ptr(myClass* d) { location = d;}  
  ~clone_ptr() { delete location; } 

  clone_ptr(const clone_ptr<myClass>& source){
    if (source.location!=nullptr){
      location=source.location->Clone();
    }
    else
      location=nullptr;
  }
  clone_ptr& operator= (const clone_ptr<myClass>& source){
    if (&source!=this){
      if (source.location!=nullptr){
    location=source.location->Clone();
      }
      else
    location=nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  myClass* operator->() { return location; }
  myClass& operator*() { return *location; }

private:
  myClass* location;
};
```

I am implementing the Clone() function in the appropriate classes as follows:

```
class myClass : public parentClass{
...
 public:
   myClass* Clone() 
   {
     return new myClass(*this);
   }
```